# Exclude handlbars templates from RequireJS optimization

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, handlebars.js, amd

I have an [Ember.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ember.js) application, and after I ran [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/) optimisation all the files got optimised and concatenated into one file including the handlebars templates, How can I exclude the templates from the optimisation and just make it load it via Ajax with text plugin?

Comment: Not what you asked about, but for best performance in production releases, consider precompiling your handlebars templates and include them in your main JS file.

Comment: True, but i wanna do that just for integration with phone gap, since mobile phones are very sensitive to js file size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this option to your build config:

`inlineText: false`

Here is [documentation](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/2.1.10/build/example.build.js#L221)